# Remove words from a text file that exist in another text file - Python

Tags: python

I have a text file containing text from five different textfiles (alltext.txt)

I also have a text file with words on each line, that needs to be removed from the alltext-file (badwords.txt).

How can I do this without making a new alltext file, but simply remove the words from badwords.txt? 
I'm very new to python.

UPDATED:

```
text=open('alltext.txt').read().split()
other_words = open('badwords.txt').readline()

for line in text:
for word in other_words:
if word == other_words:
text.remove(word)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow , maybe try the tour and be sure to read How to Ask, To improve your question, you may add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are most likely looking for Sets. They will do what you want.

Comment: I have thought of using sets, but I'm a little confused of how to use sets when working with text files.

Comment: You could load content of alltext.txt in `list` and then after removing from that list words from badwords.txt override original alltext.txt with that list.

Comment: Please show us what you tried or at least how you are thinking about it. If we do all the thinking for you, then you won't learn well. Some hints: you need to know how to read and write files. You need to know how to loop and how to check a condition (if statements). That's pretty much all you need.

Comment: I have updated my question:

Comment: @germancoder can you show an example of what is contained in `alltext.txt` e.g. is it only one word per line, or multiple words?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, or two ways, depending on what you want to do with repeated words.

```
alltext  = [ "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "foo", "bar" ]
badwords = [ "foo", "bar" ]

newtext = [ word for word in alltext if word not in set(badwords) ]
newtext = [ word for word in set(alltext) if word not in set(badwords) ]
```

Both return `['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'gamma']` with this data, but the former will keep duplicates in `alltext` the later will 'uniqueify' the newtext.

Answer (score 0):

```
bad = set([ line.strip() for line in open('badwords.txt') ])
good = [ ' '.join([ word for word in line.strip().split() if word not in bad ]) for line in open('alltext.txt') ]
out = open('alltext.txt','w')
for line in good:
    out.write(line+'\n')
out.close()
```

Comment: This writes a new file, and also assumes that `alltext.txt` only contains one word per line, and also does not preserve the order of the lines in `alltext.txt`.

Comment: The new file is only due to a typo in the filename. I thought the question specifies that there is only one word per line. I'll fix the ordering problem as well as the typo.

Comment: Now it should allow for more words per line in alltext.txt

Comment: Now your code doesn't run at all. Have you tested it? `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at line 2. Also, once you fix it, how do you cope with words that don't have a space on each side, e.g. they have comma or period after them?

Comment: `Nope. My intention was not to give a perfect working code, if there is a brace missing or a method has slightly different name, that's something anyone should be able to fix easily.` I disagree completely. An answer should not be left as wrong. I've removed my downvote since you fixed the bug in your answer.